# Filling k different sized boxes with n objects

Tags: combinatorics

Is there a known mechanism to count the number of ways in which I can fill $k$ boxes of various sizes, $r_1,...,r_k$, with $n$ objects without counting permutations of objects within a box as a separate allocation.

e.g. Suppose $n=3$, $k=2$, $r_1=1$, and $r_2=2$. Then, there are 3 objects and 2 boxes. Box 1 can fit 1 object and box 2 can fit 2 objects. Also, if object 1 in box 1 and objects 2 and 3 in box 2 is an allocation that is counted, I would not like to additionally count object 1 in box 1 and objects 3 and 2 in box 2.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that $\sum_{i=1}^{k}r_i = n$, then the answer is

$$\prod_{i=1}^{k} C(n - \sum_{j=1}^{i-1}r_j,r_i)$$

where $C$ is the binomial coefficient. This can be further reduced to

$$\frac{n!}{\prod_{i=1}^{k}r_i!}$$

Explanation - Choose $r_1$ objects and out them into box 1, then choose $r_2$ from $N - r_1$ and put them into box 2 and so on.

Comment: That was what I thought, but it isn't the correct solution when you have to do it "without counting permutations of objects within a box as a separate allocation". See the "possible duplicate" in the comments to the question

Comment: @Lovsovs I don't see where I am considering permutations within the boxes as different allocations. As far as I understand I am just computing the product of the number of ways to **choose** objects from a collection and putting into a box of given capacity.

Comment: Huh, guess you're right - I will undelete my answer then, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From your description in the question, I take it that objects are *distinct*.

The answer is directly given by the [multinomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem)

$\dbinom{n}{r_1, r_2, ... r_k}$, where $r_1+r_2+...+r_k=n$

**Added**

You might like to note a number of useful interpretations of the multinomial coefficient

- Ways to put $n$ labelled balls into $k$ labelled boxes with $r_1, r_2, .. r_k$ in boxes $1,2,...k$
- Selecting people for labelled groups (choosing $n_1$ to be labelled $1$, $n_2$ to be labelled $2$, etc
- Permutations with repetitions of indistinguishable objects, e.g. of MISSISSIPPI

For the last one, you would be familiar with $\dfrac{11!}{1!4!4!2!}$

Note that $\dfrac{11!}{1!4!4!2!} = \binom{11}1\binom{10}4\binom64\binom22= \dbinom{11}{1,4,4,2}$